# Left Coset of $H = \lbrace \epsilon, \alpha \rbrace$

Tags: abstract-algebra

"A Book of Abstract Algebra" presents the following exercise:

> In each of the following, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. For each coset, 
>   list the elements of the coset.

$$G=S_3, H= \lbrace \epsilon, \alpha \rbrace$$

Given the following definitions of $\epsilon$ and $\alpha$, respectively:

$(1 \rightarrow 1, 2 \rightarrow 2, 3 \rightarrow 3)$

$(1 \rightarrow 1, 2 \rightarrow 3, 3 \rightarrow 2)$

How can I figure out the left coset of $H$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, $S_3$ has order 6. And $H$ has order 2. So we will have $6/2=3$ cosets. One of the cosets is always $H$ itself. Then we can get the others by simply multiplying by a random element of $H$. Let's try $\beta=(1\:2\:3)$ (are you familiar with cyclic notation?). Then we have $\beta\alpha=(1\:2\:3)(2\:3)=(1\:2)$

$$\beta H=\{(1\:2\:3),(1\:2)\}$$

Then the last coset will be the two elements that isn't in either of our cosets (which are $(1\:3\:2)$ and $(1\:3)$). I will let $\gamma=(1\:3\:2)$.

So overall our three cosets are

$$\{H,\beta H,\gamma H\}$$

You can check for yourself to verify that $\gamma H=\{(1\:3\:2),(1\:3)\}$

I should add a few things I assumed that you may not have learned yet;

1) cosets all have the same size

2) cosets are equal or disjoint (which is why I knew by default what the elements of the last coset were).

3) The union of all the cosets will be the group itself (which is why I knew that there would be three, because there were two in each).

Comment: Could you please explain your reasoning for selecting $\gamma$ to be $(1 3 2)$ instead of $(1 3)$?

Comment: I could have chosen either and it'd be the same!! You can check that for yourself, it works

Answer (score 1):

We can exhaustively list the left cosets, just by *calculating* $xH$ for each $x \in S_3$. Some of these may wind up being the same, let's see:

$\epsilon H = H = \{\epsilon, \alpha\}$ (hopefully this is obvious: the identity function composed with any other function is that function).

Now, $\alpha H = \{\alpha\circ \epsilon, \alpha \circ \alpha\} = \{\alpha, \alpha^2\}= \{\alpha, \epsilon\} = H$ (since $\alpha \circ \alpha = \epsilon$, and with sets (and cosets are sets, after all) it does not matter which order we list the elements in).

Suppose $\beta$ is given by the following:

$(1 \to 2, 2\to 3, 3 \to 1)$.

Then $\beta H = \{\beta \circ \epsilon, \beta\circ \alpha\} = \{\beta, \beta\circ\alpha\}$

We can see that $\beta H \neq H$, because $\beta \in \beta H$, but $\beta \not\in H$. So this is a genuinely different coset.

There really isn't any "better" name for $\beta \circ \alpha$, but if we want to describe it explicitly, we can calculate its values:

$(\beta\circ\alpha)(1) = \beta(\alpha(1)) = \beta(1) = 2\\ (\beta\circ\alpha)(2) = \beta(\alpha(2)) = \beta(3) = 1\\ (\beta\circ\alpha)(3) = \beta(\alpha(3)) = \beta(2) = 3$,

so this is $\beta\circ\alpha:$

$(1 \to 2, 2 \to 1, 3 \to 3)$.

$\beta^2$ is another element of $S_3$ we have not "described" yet, which does the following (as you can verify by calculating $\beta \circ \beta$):

$(1 \to 3, 2 \to 1, 3 \to 2)$.

By actually computing $\beta^2H$, we find $\beta^2H = \{\beta^2,\beta^2\circ\alpha\}$. Note that since $\beta^2 \not \in H$, and $\beta^2 \not\in \beta H$ (you can see that $\beta^2$ differs from $\epsilon,\alpha,\beta$ and $\beta\circ\alpha$, these are all different functions), we now have a third distinct coset from our first two.

Well, we know that $\beta\circ\alpha \in S_3$, so we calculate:

$(\beta\circ\alpha)H = \{(\beta\circ\alpha)\circ\epsilon,(\beta\circ\alpha)\circ\alpha\} = \{\beta\circ\alpha,\beta\circ(\alpha\circ\alpha)\}$

$=\{\beta\circ\alpha,\beta\}$, which is the same SET as $\beta H$.

So far, we've computed $5$ left cosets, but only found $3$ "different" ones (and two duplicates). The only left coset we have yet to compute is $(\beta^2\circ\alpha)H$ (you should verify that $S_3 = \{\epsilon,\alpha,\beta,\beta^2,\beta\circ\alpha,\beta^2\circ\alpha\}$ is indeed a complete list). So here we go:

$(\beta^2\circ\alpha)H = \{(\beta^2\circ\alpha)\circ\epsilon, (\beta^2\circ\alpha)\circ\alpha\} = \{\beta^2\circ\alpha,\beta^2\circ(\alpha\circ\alpha)\}$

$=\{\beta^2\circ\alpha,\beta^2\} = \beta^2H$

So out of $6$ "possible" cosets, we find, in fact, that there are only $3$ distinct ones, and $3$ duplicates (one of each):

$H = \alpha H\\ \beta H = (\beta\circ\alpha)H\\ \beta^2H = (\beta^2\circ\alpha)H$

Note that these *partition* $S_3$, that is:

$S_3 = H \cup \beta H \cup \beta^2H$, and:

$H \cap \beta H = \emptyset\\ H \cap \beta^2H = \emptyset\\ \beta H \cap \beta^2H = \emptyset$.

This should lead you to suspect we have an equivalence relation involved here, which is, in point of fact, true.